# Read CSV with comma delimiter (sorting issue while importing csv)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, opencsv

I am trying to open a csv file by skipping first 5 rows. The data is not getting aligned in dataframe. [See screenshot of file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdK4l.png)

```
PO = pd.DataFrame()
PO = pd.read_table(acct.csv',sep='\t',skiprows=5,skip_blank_lines=True)
PO
```

Comment: is this aligned before input? or do you want to align chronically after import? Because the solution depends on import or input.

Comment: The subject says comma delimiter, but the code specifically uses tabs.

Comment: hi, I would like to get this align chronically after import.

Answer (score 0):

try to set it after import datewise as below.
First sort your data with proper import as it is sticked to the index values. see data image again and data as well. So, when you have proper separator / delimiter you can do following.

```
do = pd.read_csv('check_test.csv', "r", delimiter='\t',   skiprows=range(1, 7),skip_blank_lines=True, encoding="utf8")

d01 = do.iloc[:,1:7]
d02 = d01.sort_values('Date,Reference,Debit')
```

This is sorting the values into the way you want.

Comment: It is not working bro. KeyError: "None of ['Transaction Date'] are in the columns"

Comment: you have to take header while importing csv so that it can read column header Transaction Date

Comment: The file has unstructured data till row 5, post that header starts at row 6. I did considered it.

Comment: put first 10 entries of the dataframe here with question so that anyone or I can check at my end. with image only it is difficult.

Comment: Transaction Date,Reference,Debit Amount,Credit Amount,Transaction Ref1,Transaction Ref2,Transaction Ref3
0 01 Oct 2010,POS, 19.90, ,JAY GEE EN,,,
1 29 Sep 2010,POS, 50.50, ,THIS FASHI,,,
2 28 Sep 2010,TC, 74.83, ,BY :PASIR RIS-PUN...
3 27 Sep 2010,POS, 31.20, ,HANG TEN E,,,
4 26 Sep 2010,POS, 16.80, ,NEWBIE GIF,,,
5 26 Sep 2010,AWL, 50.00, ,31826174,R'VALE PZ EB...
6 24 Sep 2010,POS, 15.00, ,BATA SHOE,,,
7 22 Sep 2010,POS, 66.00, ,GIORDANO O,,,
8 21 Sep 2010,POS, 13.65, ,NTUC FP,,,
9 20 Sep 2010,ITR, , 500.00,I-BANK,Bangaram,,
10 20 Sep 2010,ITR, 500.00, ,048-2-026399 : I-BAN...

Comment: please send in proper way like you shared code above that formatting will ease to copy.

Comment: copy past is now working in correct format .. let me send two rows

Comment: Transaction Date,Reference,Debit Amount,Credit Amount,Transaction Ref1,Transaction Ref2,Transaction Ref3

Comment: 01 Oct 2010,POS, 19.90, ,JAY GEE EN,,,

Comment: 29 Sep 2010,POS, 50.50, ,THIS FASHI,,,

Comment: 28 Sep 2010,TC, 74.83, ,BY      :PASIR RIS-PUNGGOL TO,PART/REF:             C89080299830,,

Comment: Look at the first column. index. If you keep index, the data will sort with index. if you skip the index and reindex, it will sort according to date. Please first take the data with proper separator either comma or tab or so. remove first index column and import.

Comment: Please flag the answer with arrow up.